# When using a vertical folder structure for AngularJS (MeanJS) where to put shared Services

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-filters, meanjs

I am using [MEANJS](http://meanjs.org/docs.html). And have created some crud modules for articles, bank-accounts, incomes and expenses. For the incomes and expenses i would like a service that finds the name of a bank account using it's `_id`.

So I came up with this filter:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('incomes').filter('findBy', [
    function() {
      return function(input, id) {
        var i=0, len=input.length;
        for (; i<len; i++) {
          if (input[i]._id === id) {
            return input[i];
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
]);
```

But if I want to use the filter from both income's and expense's controller I should put it in a shared filter? So in this vertical folder structure: where do I preferably put shared filters and shared services.

(I thought I could put the filter on the "app" using `var app=angular.module("app",[])` but I dont see the usage of app anywhere in the MEANJS boilerplate code and i don't want to break the structure)

**Vertical Structure:**

```
|-css 
|-img 
|-js 
|-modules 
|---articles 
|-----config 
|-----controllers 
|-----services 
|-----tests 
|-----views
|---core
|-----config
|-----controllers
|-----tests
|-----views
|---users
|-----config
|-----controllers
|-----services
|-----views
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every shared element I use a 'shared' module that I inject in the main app, like any other module. In this module I have all helpers used in various modules, as well as constants and other stuff of this kind.

Is there something preventing you to do the same ?

Comment: I am just curious in if there is any "by the book method" for handling this. It is not mentioned in MEANJS docs, even though they ramble a bit about the vertical structure. I will try your solution.